# Cannot update a component (`BrowserRouter`) while rendering a different component (`Login`)

Tags: reactjs

I am getting this warning when I have worked on my react project:

> Warning: Cannot update a component (`BrowserRouter`) while rendering a different component (`Login`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Login`

My Code:

**Index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
<BrowserRouter>
<React.StrictMode>
  <App />
</React.StrictMode>
</BrowserRouter>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Specific part of the code from **Login.js**:

```
 if (accessToken) {
    navigate(from, { replace: true });
}
```

This specific part of code triggers this warning.
When I navigate from the login page to another page after logging in, it shows this warning.

Answer (score 3):

It has to be wrapped in an effect so that it runs after it rendered, not during the render phase.

```
function  MyComponent() {
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (accessToken) {
        navigate(from, { replace: true });
    }
    
  }, [])
  
  
  return (<div>{/* ... */}</div>)
  
}
```