# Warning: Cannot update a component (`BrowserRouter`) while rendering a different component (`FormSocialIcon`)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, react-router

**I am getting warning [ Cannot update a component (`BrowserRouter`) while rendering a different component (`FormSocialIcon`).] while login.How to solve this warning?**

**FormSocialIcon component**

```
const FormSocialIcon = () => {
const [signInWithGoogle, user, loading, error] = useSignInWithGoogle(auth);

const navigate = useNavigate();
let location = useLocation();

let from = location.state?.from?.pathname || "/";

let errorMessage;
if (error) {
    errorMessage =
        <div>
            <p className='text-red-500 font-bold'>Error: {error.message}</p>
        </div>
}
if (loading) {
    return <Loader></Loader>
}

if (user) {
    navigate(from, { replace: true });
}

return (
    <div>
        <div className='flex justify-center items-center mt-3'>
            <div className='bg-indigo-600 w-60 h-0.5'></div>
            <div className='mx-2 font-semibold'>Or</div>
            <div className='bg-indigo-600 w-60 h-0.5'></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            {errorMessage}
            <button onClick={() => signInWithGoogle()} className='w-full md:w-96 flex justify-center mt-5 mx-auto p-2 border-2 border-indigo-500 rounded font-semibold outline-none hover:font-bold hover:transition-all hover:scale-110'>Continue with google<img className='w-5 ml-2' src={googleIcon} alt="" /></button>
        </div>
    </div>
);
```

};

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot update a component (\`BrowserRouter\`) while rendering a different component (\`Login\`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72150678/cannot-update-a-component-browserrouter-while-rendering-a-different-componen)

Answer (score 4):

So I had been struggling with the same issue and I think it would work using the 'useEffect()' hook. It would end up looking something like this.

```
// Replace this:
if (user) {
    navigate(from, { replace: true });
}
// With this
useEffect(()=>{
if (user) {
    navigate(from, { replace: true });
}
},[navigate,user])
```

There are probably better ways of doing this, but this worked for me.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I've spent quite a few hours trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion a better solution to avoid this kind of problem and to be sure you will not try to render the last part of your code, is to use the [Navigate](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/navigate) component

```
import { Navigate } from "react-router-dom";

if (user) {
 return <Navigate to={from} replace={true}>
}
```